# impacts of high value row cache?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ccm

Recently I have gone through a tutorial about key cache and row cache.
Can anyone help me with some real time examples where these cache can impact?
And what is the impact if we increase these values in config file?

On using desc table I found this

```
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
```